# How to reclassify a raster in R and keep only certain values after reclassification?

Tags: raster, r, reclassify

I have Cropscape Data Layer raster with different vegetation types. I want to only keep pixels with values 43 and/or 54. I'm doing something wrong with the `reclassify()` function in R's `raster` package.

Here is a demo raster and the reclassification table I use for reclassifying:

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(ncol=10,nrow=10)
values(r1) <- c(rep(10,10), rep(43,10), rep(44,20), rep(54,40), rep(70,20))

rcl <- matrix(data=c(-1,42,NA,43,43,1,44,53,NA,54,54,2,55,255,NA), ncol=3, byrow=T)
#also tried
#rcl <- matrix(data=c(1,42,0,43,43,1,44,53,0,54,54,2,55,255,0), ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

I tried

```
r2 = reclassify(r1, rcl, right=NA)
```

And I still get a bunch of zero values. In this example case, 50 zeros. I want the raster to hold only the pixels of interest, those valued 1 and 2. In this case, the raster would return the 10 pixels valued at 1 and the 40 pixels valued at 2.

I did something similar to this sometime last year and created the rasters as I wanted. I have notes, but not the complete code and it looks like I used a different reclassification table with 2 columns instead of 3 columns.

```
rcl <- matrix(data=c(43,1,54,2), ncol=2, byrow=T)
```

and

```
r2 = reclassify(r1, rcl, otherNA=TRUE)
```

But that doesn't do now what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your data are integers then you could stretch your edges to include the integers you want and not fiddle with the `include.lowest` and `right` parameters which are probably the Right Way to do this. In other words:

```
> rcl[,1] = rcl[,1]-0.2
> rcl[,2] = rcl[,2]+0.2
```

so that:

```
> rcl
     [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.8  42.2   NA
[2,] 42.8  43.2    1
[3,] 43.8  53.2   NA
[4,] 53.8  54.2    2
[5,] 54.8 255.2   NA
```

and then:

```
> r2 = reclassify(r1, rcl)
> as.matrix(r2)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [5,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [6,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [7,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [8,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to change the first value of `rcl` to -1 instead of 1 to get all zeros out of the way.